# Editing autocomplete settings in Visual Studio 2013 (PTVS)

Tags: python, visual-studio, autocomplete, ptvs

I am trying to switch from Pycharm to Visual Studio 2013 (PTVS), however I cannot find how to change settings for auto-completion popups. For example, in Pycharm whenever you start writing something, it automatically gives you a list of possible keywords, like in screenshots below.
If I start to write 'co' pycharm lets me choose 'consecutive' which is an already defined boolean. Is there any way to change these settings in visual studio? I have went through the settings menu like 20 times now, and I  am completely stuck.

```
screenshot of pycharm:
http://i61.tinypic.com/20960wn.png

screenshot of visual studio 2013:
http://i62.tinypic.com/2qtilg1.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself - PTVS doesn't support this feature, however there is a plugin, which can be downloaded here, which supposedly fixes this issue:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/644b4359-5eeb-4ba5-9374-78a8507761f0

However, after further inspection, it is broken and doesnt work half as good as pycharm's autocomplete. Most of the time it popups a message saying 'no suggestions' which becomes seriously annoying getting that msg after every single letter. 
Bottomline - it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported with PTVS.  Per the [completions section](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Editor-Features#completions) found on the GitHub wiki.

> Completions can be shown at any time by pressing Ctrl+J or Ctrl+Space, or may be triggered automatically by certain commands (such as import), operators (such as a period/full stop), or by typing at any place where completions are likely to be helpful.